# Cant start a process if it is already running

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I've tried lots of stuff so far, and the only thing i can seem to get to work is to have two files that "loop" off of eachother, ill start with some more info
Im using the package `pkg` to compile my javascript into an exe, everything works just fine there. However, im trying to create a loop of sorts that keeps starting the same exe once it is opened as a little troll, but it just runs once and then it stops. I can get around this by having two exes that will run eachother, however i'd like to use a solution that doesnt take up so much space. Since it seems that it wont run the exe if its already running, whats a way to get around this using javascript child processes? Sorry if this isn't enough info, let me know if more is needed. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code for you scenario as well? It would help the community to answer your question, thanks!

Comment: Not much to really say about it to be fair! but i'll put down what im using to run the exe that i've compiled

```const {spawn} = require("child_process")
    spawn("index-win.exe", {detached: true})```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. You want to re-run the same thing after it ends? Or something else? Either way—doesn’t spawn have an event for the process ending?